# Count the number of elements are matching with for the given xpath expression

Tags: selenium, xpath

How to count the number of elements are matching with for the given xpath expression

```
xpath: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'richedittext_instance')]"))
```

all i need is the count.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
//Assume driver is intialized properly.
int iCount = 0;
iCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("Xpath Value")).size());
```

The `iCount` has the number of elements having the same `xpath` value.

Answer (score 1):

Another option
If you are basing your requirements *strictly* on the need to use Selenium, you might be able to do something like this using WebElements and getting the size of the returned list:

```
List<WebElement> myListToCheck=currentDriver.findElements(By.xpath("somePath"));
if(myListToCheck.size()>0){
//do this
}else{
//do something else
}
```

Or just simply returning the size of the returned list; if that's all you really want to get from it...

```
int mySize=myListToCheck.size()
```

I believe once you have an established WebElements list, you can also use iterators to go over that list. 
Helpful, I dunno... just providing another way to get to the same end-game.

Answer (score 0):

*Not working in Selenium, which only allows to return nodes from XPath, not primitives like the number returned by `count(...)`. Kept for reference and is valid for most other tools offering a more complete XPath API.*

You should only return least possible amount of data from the query. `count(//div[contains(@id,'richedittext_instance')])` counts the number of results *within* XPath and thus is faster as all the elements do not have to be passed from the XPath engine to Selenium.

I can't help you with how to fetch this as n `int` out of selenium, but this should be easy stuff.

Comment: I don't think this works as I have been trying to use this already unsuccessfully.

Comment: Since then I learned Selenium is not able to return the `count(...)` value. Edited but kept the answer for reference.

Comment: When you say "Other tools" what tools are you referring to? I ask as over the past 2 years I have been developing a browser game bot and have used so many different tools non of which managed to "mimic" a human the way Selenium Webdriver can.

Comment: There are several dozens of XPath processors. But I do not know about another one with similar features like Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "Your_XPath")
```

This outputs a list of `selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement`s (in my Firefox browser).

Finally, find out the length of the list:

```
len(elements)
```

**NB.**: Please note that I have written `find_elements()` (plural) and NOT `find_element()`. Both of them are different. `find_element()` only returns the first matched web element, but to find the list of all the matched web elements, we have to use `find_elements()`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to print the number of elements that share the same xpath. Using the below code - I am able to print the number of elements in both console and extent report.

```
enter code here
```

`List<WebElement> noOfTiles = baseTestSuite.getDriver() .findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[contains(@resource-id,'pf_tile_outer')]")); if(noOfTiles.size()>0){ System.out.println("No. of tiles on Add cash page are:"+" "+noOfTiles.size()); int numberOfTiles = noOfTiles.size(); // converting the int to String because getLogger is not to print the integer. String s=String.valueOf(numberOfTiles); getLogger().log(LogStatus.PASS, s); }`