# Count number of elements using xpath() in javascript on selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am writing test script in selenium webdriver using javascript.

**I am using mocha and phantomJS too.**

I want to count total no. of `<li>` in a `<ul>` having a particular id.

I am using this script:

```
var majorSize = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id, 'side-menu')]/li[not(contains(@class, 'nav-header'))]")).size();
console.log(majorSize);
```

I used the reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766807/count-the-number-of-elements-are-matching-with-for-the-given-xpath-expression)

But I am getting error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

In javascript, I can use this code also:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id, 'side-menu')]/li[not(contains(@class, 'nav-header'))]")).then(function(majorSize)
{
   console.log(majorSize.legth)
});
console.log(majorSize.legnth);
```

The above script has majorLink scope withing the then() function only. So it can't be used outside. But I need it to be used outside as well.

If I define something like `var majorSize`, then also it just displays 0 outside the then() function.

What wrong am I doing?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<ul id="side-menu" class="nav">
    <li class="nav-header">
    <img class="logo" alt="Track Revenue" src="/images/3c4939d.png">
    <div class="logo-element"> TR </div>
    </li>
    <li class="">
    <a href="#home">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
    <span class="nav-label">Tr Admin Menu</span>
    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/user/">All Users</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/company/">All Companies</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/device/">Devices</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/email/">Send Email</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/impersonate">Impersonate User</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/encrypttest">Test Encryption</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="">
    <a href="#home">
    <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
    <span class="nav-label">Campaigns</span>
    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    <li>
    <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/campaign_overview.php">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/campaign_update_cpc.php">CPC Update</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/campaign_update_subids.php">SubID Update</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/campaign_v2.php">Add Campaign</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#home">
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
    <span class="nav-label">Stats</span>
    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/stats_campaign_v2.php">Campaign Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/stats_week_day_v2.php">Week / Day Parting Stats</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#home">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
    <span class="nav-label">Reports</span>
    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/report_custom.php">Custom Data Reports</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/report_subid.php">SubID Analysis Report</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/completed_report.php">Scheduled Reports</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#home">
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
    <span class="nav-label">Settings</span>
    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
        <li>
        <a href="/profile/">Account</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/plan/">Plan Management</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/settings_groups.php">Campaign Groups</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/settings_network.php">Affiliate Networks</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/settings_sources.php">Traffic Source</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/manage/user/">Manage Users</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/manage/company/">Manage Company</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/settings_rules.php">Blocking & Filter Rules</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/domains.php">Domains</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/campaign_archive.php">Campaign Maintenance</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I already tried that, sir. Its displaying undefined. @har07

Comment: can you please put that html code with question? Is that under javascript? iframe?

Comment: @HelpingHands, I have added the HTML script, sir.

Comment: No help. :( I am really stuck.

Comment: did you use try & catch to get exact exception?

Comment: how can I do that? ca you help?

Comment: Please refer Try-Catch syntax here : http://www.javatpoint.com/try-catch-block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88366/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-smruti-singh).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want all the `LI`s (and only the `LI`s) that are children of the `UL` with `id = side-menu`. Is that correct? This is in Java but hopefully you can translate it.

```
List<WebElement> lis = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#side-menu > li"));
System.out.println(lis.size());
```

This CSS selector means find an element with an ID (#) of side-menu that has children `LI`s. These are direct children and not descendants.

Comment: Please leave a comment when you downvote. If you are downvoting because it's not phantomJS, it's not like it's hard to translate. it's just copy/paste the CSS Selector and probably put `var` where `List<WebElement>` was... oh and put `.length` instead of `.size()`.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. By the way, I tried with .lenth also. Its stating undefned as well.

Comment: You typo'd there with `.lenth` ... did you actually try `.length`?